Module Striprtf in UDF returns error in Fabric PySpark
This is my first post in this community and I am excited.
Environment
I am using a Notebook in Microsoft Fabric. The language is PySpark.
Objective
I want to convert a column in RTF to plaintext.
pip install striprtf

# Import the modules needed
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Wrap function in UDF
my_udf = udf(lambda x:rtf_to_text(x), StringType())

# Create new column with plaintext
df.withColumn("plaintext", my_udf(col("formattedtext"))) \
  .show(truncate=False)

Challenge
I have installed the module striprtf, imported the needed functions and defined a UDF. Still I get an error message for the last command saying "No module named 'striprtf'". If I test the function 'rtf_to_text' on a variable it works.

Has the library loaded ok? try pip show striprtf to check

Thanks, Jon. I didnt know that command. The library loaded okay. Do I have to consider the note "you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.". I would get it every time i run the script.
